# Why does my app crash running on android phone but runs in eclipse? Using libgdx

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apache

When I run the game in eclipse the desktop version runs fine. When I try to run it on my S3 I get the following in eclipse logcat and the unfortunately app has stopped error on the phone. I'm at a loss. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I do also have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in the manifest.

```
03-18 22:28:24.214: W/dalvikvm(20121): VFY: unable to resolve static field 7070 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/impl/DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy;
03-18 22:28:24.214: W/dalvikvm(20121): VFY: unable to resolve static field 7270 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy;
03-18 22:28:24.214: W/dalvikvm(20121): VFY: unable to resolve static field 7308 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultUserTokenHandler;
03-18 22:28:24.214: W/dalvikvm(20121): VFY: unable to resolve static field 7088 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/impl/NoConnectionReuseStrategy;
03-18 22:28:24.214: W/dalvikvm(20121): VFY: unable to resolve static field 7070 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/impl/DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy;
03-18 22:28:24.214: W/dalvikvm(20121): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 14632: Lorg/apache/http/client/protocol/RequestDefaultHeaders;.<init> (Ljava/util/Collection;)V
03-18 22:28:24.214: W/dalvikvm(20121): VFY: unable to resolve static field 7271 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler;
03-18 22:28:24.314: W/dalvikvm(20121): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15027: Lorg/apache/http/conn/routing/HttpRoute;.getLocalSocketAddress ()Ljava/net/InetSocketAddress;
03-18 22:28:24.314: W/dalvikvm(20121): VFY: unable to resolve static field 7924 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter;
03-18 22:28:24.314: W/dalvikvm(20121): Exception Ljava/lang/NoSuchFieldError; thrown while initializing Lorg/apache/http/impl/io/DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory;
03-18 22:28:24.314: W/dalvikvm(20121): Exception Ljava/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError; thrown while initializing Lorg/apache/http/impl/conn/ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory;
03-18 22:28:24.324: W/dalvikvm(20121): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41675438)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 55349
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:487)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:147)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:136)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:112)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:726)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:58)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at com.mydemo.game.Util.getHttp(Util.java:300)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at com.mydemo.game.CharacterSelect.<init>(CharacterSelect.java:65)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at com.mydemo.game.STGame.create(STGame.java:12)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:334)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:72)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:84)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<clinit>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:59)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    ... 12 more
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter.INSTANCE
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:52)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:56)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<clinit>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:46)
03-18 22:28:24.324: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    ... 15 more
03-18 22:28:24.354: D/SensorManager(20121): unregisterListener::  Listener= com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput$SensorListener@42343d60
03-18 22:28:24.354: I/SensorManager(20121): Set normal delay = true
03-18 22:28:24.354: D/SensorManager(20121): unregisterListener::  Listener= com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput$SensorListener@42344e78
03-18 22:28:24.354: I/SensorManager(20121): Set normal delay = true
03-18 22:28:24.354: I/AndroidInput(20121): sensor listener tear down
03-18 22:28:24.354: I/AndroidGraphics(20121): Managed meshes/app: { }
03-18 22:28:24.354: I/AndroidGraphics(20121): Managed textures/app: { }
03-18 22:28:24.354: I/AndroidGraphics(20121): Managed shaders/app: { }
03-18 22:28:24.354: I/AndroidGraphics(20121): Managed buffers/app: { }
```

If additional info is needed let me know and I'll post it. Thanks in advance.

Edit: getHttp function

```
public static String getHttp(String url) throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException {

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

        // Create a custom response handler
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new ResponseHandler<String>() {

            public String handleResponse(final HttpResponse response)
                    throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    return entity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(entity)
                            : null;
                } else {
                    throw new ClientProtocolException(
                            "Unexpected response status: " + status);
                }
            }

        };
        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        // System.out.println(responseBody);
        return responseBody;
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The http connection is to a live webserver php page that returns json. I can access that url and it shows the correct data from a browser on the phone.

Comment: Via usb cable. The app ran fine before adding the code to pull the json over web (it was hard coded for testing). Starting on a different screen that doesn't access the web runs fine as well. It seems to be limited to something in http but I can't tell what.

Comment: I'm not accessing anything by ip. It's a valid, live domain.

Comment: The phone isn't using pc for internet connection, only to load the apk from eclipse. It uses normal wifi for internet. The domain is hard coded and works fine if I put it in the phone web browser.

Comment: I have, still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the `getHttp()` method and its related code in `Util.java`?

Comment: function posted. It uses the apache.org libraries.